# Having trouble when introducing elif or else with python project

Tags: python

I got my program to work how I want it to until I introduce the alternative for currentCurrency being USD. I want it to run through the first set of if statements if it is CAD for currentCurrency but run through the next set of if statements if currentCurrency is USD, I am new to python and can't seem to get it to work as soon as I introduce the else or elif. I have read through other similar questions and watched youtube videos but still cant seem to see where I am going wrong. I appreciate the help.

```
CAD_USD = 0.9785
CAD_EUR = 0.7935
CAD_GBP = 0.6387
CAD_YEN = 79.9794
CAD_CNY = 6.4295
CAD_CHF = 0.9614
CAD_INR = 53.8968

#Value of USD currency to other currencies
USD_CAD = 1.0220
USD_EUR = 0.7764
USD_GBP = 0.6250
USD_YEN = 78.2584
USD_CNY = 6.2895
USD_CHF = 0.9407
USD_INR = 52.7345

#Value of Eur currency to other currencies
EUR_CAD = 1.2602
EUR_USD = 1.28779
EUR_GBP = 0.8049
EUR_YEN = 100.7700
EUR_CNY = 8.0987
EUR_CHF = 1.2113
EUR_INR = 67.9060
#Value of GBP to other currencies
GBP_CAD = 1.565
GBP_USD = 1.6000
GBP_EUR = 1.2424
GBP_YEN = 125.2000
GBP_CNY = 10.0611
GBP_CHF = 1.5052
GBP_INR = 84.3593
#Prompts user for data to work with for conversion

currentCurrency= input("Please enter currency in hand:")
requiredCurrency= input("Please enter currency required:")
currentAmount =  float (input ("Please enter amount(currency value):"))

#Converting CAD currency

if currentCurrency == "CAD" or "cad":
    if requiredCurrency == "USD" or "usd":
        conversion= currentAmount*CAD_USD
        if currentCurrency == "CAD" or "cad":
            if requiredCurrency == "EUR" or "eur":
                conversion= currentAmount*CAD_EUR
                if currentCurrency == "CAD" or "cad":
                    if requiredCurrency == "GBP" or "gbp":
                        conversion= currentAmount*CAD_GBP
                        if currentCurrency == "CAD" or "cad":
                            if requiredCurrency == "YEN" or "yen":
                                conversion= currentAmount*CAD_YEN
                                if currentCurrency == "CAD" or "cad":
                                    if requiredCurrency == "CNY" or "cny":
                                        conversion= currentAmount*CAD_CNY
                                        if currentCurrency == "CAD" or "cad":
                                            if requiredCurrency == "CHF" or "chf":
                                                conversion= currentAmount*CAD_CHF
                                                if currentCurrency == "CAD" or "cad":
                                                    if requiredCurrency == "INR" or "inr":
                                                        conversion= currentAmount*CAD_INR
                                                        a1 = round(conversion)    
                                                        print(currentAmount, " in CAD is equivalent to",a1," in", requiredCurrency)
                                                        elif currentCurrency == "USD" or "usd":
                                                            else requiredCurrency == "CAD" or "cad":
                                                                conversion= currentAmount*USD_CAD
                                                                if currentCurrency == "USD" or "usd":
                                                                    if requiredCurrency == "EUR" or "eur":
                                                                        conversion= currentAmount*USD_EUR
                                                                        if currentCurrency == "USD" or "usd":
                                                                            if requiredCurrency == "GBP" or "gbp":
                                                                                conversion= currentAmount*USD_GBP
                                                                                if currentCurrency == "USD" or "usd":
                                                                                    if requiredCurrency == "YEN" or "yen":
                                                                                        conversion= currentAmount*USD_YEN
                                                                                        if currentCurrency == "USD" or "usd":
                                                                                            if requiredCurrency == "CNY" or "cny":
                                                                                                conversion= currentAmount*USD_CNY
                                                                                                if currentCurrency == "USD" or "usd":
                                                                                                    if requiredCurrency == "CHF" or "chf":
                                                                                                        conversion= currentAmount*USD_CHF
                                                                                                        if currentCurrency == "USD" or "usd":
                                                                                                            if requiredCurrency == "INR" or "inr":
                                                                                                                conversion= currentAmount*USD_INR
                                                                                                                a1 = round(conversion)    
                                                                                                                print(currentAmount, " in USD is equivalent to",a1," in", requiredCurrency)
```

Comment: Your elif needs to be in the same indentation as the if. But that aside, this code is really convoluted. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Once you have the USD_xxx values you have already defined all the other crosses.

Comment: There a numerous issues with your code. First, it's a nightmare to read. Second, `if currenntCurrency == "USD" or "usd"` doesn't do what you think it does. Third, this is a really bad way to go about designing logic branches. Check the current currency *first* in an `if-elif-else` structure, and *then* inside each branch check against the required currency.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning about the `dict` type, as it would massively reduce the amount of code you'd need to write/read/maintain/debug.

Comment: @RaniSharim thank you and I know it is. But this is how my prof is getting us to do a project for an assignment. Tts not the best way to do it but we aren't allowed to create more then what she has taught us. As of at the moment I open to how anyone code it better. I am trying to ask the user what currency they have, the currency they want, and how much of the current currency they have is. Then convert it to the amount they would have with the new currency. The data used for currencies is from the table she has given us for currency conversion amounts.

Comment: @user17162404 - I'm quite shure this is not what your professor has in mind as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could structure a branch for the case when `currentCurrency == "CAD"`:

```py
if currentCurrency == "CAD":
    if requiredCurrency == "USD":
        pass
    elif requiredCurrency == "EUR":
        pass
    elif requiredCurrency == "GBP":
        pass
    elif requiredCurrency == "YEN":
        pass
    elif requiredCurrency == "CNY":
        pass
    elif requiredCurrency == "CHF":
        pass
    elif requiredCurrency == "INR":
        pass
```

Notice that if `currentCurrency != "CAD"` this entire block is skipped over. This is the behavior you generally want, and is known as "short-circuiting". In essence, you want to choose a logic branch *as soon as possible* to avoid checking unnecessary/redundant cases.

Notice also that these are single conditions: `if currentCurrency == "CAD"`. You can do this by taking advantage of the `str.upper()` function, which returns an all-caps version of the string, and calling this method on the input strings:

```py
currentCurrency= input("Please enter currency in hand:").upper()
requiredCurrency= input("Please enter currency required:").upper()
```

Comment: So at the end of the day, after all your first level `if` statements are defined, you should only check `currentCurrency` a number of times equal to the number of currencies you want to be able to convert. So if you want to be able to accept `CAD`, `USD`, `EUR`, `GBP`, then you should have four blocks identical to what I posted, one each for those four currencies. You should never have to check `currentCurrency` more times than that.